# Suppose $f(z)$ is defined on $[0,1]$, where $f(0)<0$, $f(1)>0$, and $f''(z)<0$. Is $x$ with $f(x)=0$ unique?

Tags: functions

Consider a twice differentiable function $f(z)$ on the unit interval, where $f(0)<0$ and $f(1)>0$. The intermediate value theorem says that there exists at least one $x$ with $f(x)=0$. My question is whether $x$ is unique.

The answer would obviously be “yes” if $f(z)$ was strictly increasing. However, all I know about $f(z)$ is that it is strictly concave, i.e. the second derivative is strictly negative. Is this problem a special case of a well-known theorem that I could quote (I would be surprised if not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f''<0$, then $f'$ is decreasing. Suppose that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$, with $0<x_0<x_1<1$. Then, by Rolle's theorem, $f'(x_2)=0$ for some $x_2\in[x_1,x_0]$. So, $f'(x)\leqslant 0$ if $x\geqslant x_2$ and so $f$ is decreasing on $[x_2,1]$. But $f(1)>0$ and $f(x_1)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. $f''(x)<0$ means that $f'$ is strictly decreasing. Therefore there is a unique maximum point $x_0$ in $(0,1)$ where $f'(x_0)=0$. Note that $f(0)<0$ and $f(1)>0$ imply that $f(x_0)>0$, $f$ is strictly increasing in $[0,x_0]$ and strictly decreasing in $[x_0,1]$ Can you take it from here?